# Way to preserve formatting for lists when copy / pasting from table cell?

Tags: ms-word, office-interop

My Word interop application needs to get content out of a cell of a table in a word document. The problem is, that the formatting for some items seems broken. For example the last item of a list does not have the list style applyied. Headings are only normal text etc.

The same happens if you create a table, create a list in the table and try to copy / paste the list to somewhere else.

Has anyone else had this problem and maybe found a solution? Is there any way to trick word into giving the correct formatting?
Thanks in advance

Example code

```
Range range = cell.range;
range.MoveEnd(WdUnits.wdCharacter, -1);
...
range.FormattedText.copy()
```

The range includes the end-of-cell marker which should not be exported. I just noticed, when not altering the range, list are correctly formatted but the whole cell is exported as a table, which is bad because i want to import the content into another document (where this would nest tables infinitly)

Word2010 v14.06.6112.5000

Comment: Check your smart copy/paste word options, just a hunch. Also make sure the selection you are pasting at isnt forcing it to "normal". Just quick hunches without having word in front of me. How are you copying/pasting?  Can you edit your ? And post relevant code?

Comment: @jJack, thanks for your idea but sadly the copy/paste options only offer options to change paste behaviour, not copy behaviour. Using other settings, copy/pasting within the same document works though...